# Getting the character returned by read() in BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

How can I convert an integer returned by the `read()` in a `BufferedReader` to the actual character value and then append it to a String? The `read()` returns the integer that represents the character read. How when I do this, it doesn't append the actual character into the String. Instead, it appends the integer representation itself to the String.

```
int c;
String result = "";

while ((c = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
    //Since c is an integer, how can I get the value read by incoming.read() from here?
    response += c;   //This appends the integer read from incoming.read() to the String. I wanted the character read, not the integer representation
}
```

What should I do to get the actual data read?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just cast `c` to a `char`.

Also, don't ever use `+=` on a `String` in a loop. It is O(n^2), rather than the expected O(n). Use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` instead.

```
int c;
StringBuilder response= new StringBuilder();

while ((c = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
    // Since c is an integer, cast it to a char.
    // If c isn't -1, it will be in the correct range of char.
    response.append( (char)c ) ;  
}
String result = response.toString();
```

Comment: @JoeBlow Thank you for the kind comment. Regarding your edit, I feel closing the reader is the responsibility of whoever created the reader. Because we don't see the creation of the reader, closing it is not appropriate here, and beyond the scope of the answer..

Answer (score 5):

you could also read it into a char buffer

```
char[] buff = new char[1024];
int read;
StringBuilder response= new StringBuilder();
while((read = bufferedReader.read(buff)) != -1) {

    response.append( buff,0,read ) ;  
}
```

this will be more efficient than reading char per char

Answer (score 4):

Cast it to a char first:

```
response += (char) c;
```

Also (unrelated to your question), in that particular example you should use a StringBuilder, not a String.