# Java BufferedReader file IO giving odd, inaccurate output

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

The idea here is that the program goes character by character through a text file, and counts the occurrences of each letter, then stores the amount of occurrences into an array. However, I'm getting odd, inaccurate output I can't seem to fix. Answers online don't seem to be helping. It's probably something very simple that I'm missing, but I need an extra nudge in the right direction.

```
char token;
char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
int[] occurences = new int[25];
BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("plaintext.txt"));

while (inFile.read() > -1) {
    token = (char)inFile.read();
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        if (Character.compare(token, alphabet[i]) == 0) {
            occurences[i] += 1;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < occurences.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(occurences[i]);
}

inFile.close();
```

given that plaintext.txt contains the following:

```
aaa
aaa
bbb
[];'
abcdefgh qrstuv
```

I get the following output:

```
3
1
1
0 
1
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're ignoring many of the chars read in, don't do that! This, `while (inFile.read() > -1) {` reads and discards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
while (inFile.read() > -1) {
    token = (char)inFile.read();
```

translates to: read one char, discard it.  Read another, treat it.  Read one more, discard, etc.

You can get inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771303/getting-the-character-returned-by-read-in-bufferedreader) - essentially:

```
int c;
while ((c = inFile.read()) != -1) {
    // there's no need to declare token before this loop
    char token =  (char) c ;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you! It worked. I get it now, so I was throwing characters away due to calling it twice?

Comment: @LordValkyrie indeed, you were throwing away 50% of your input

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring half the chars read in with

```
while (inFile.read() > -1) {
    token = (char)inFile.read();
```

Don't do that. Read and use them all

```
int intToken = 0;
while ((intToken = inFile.read()) > -1) {
    token = (char)intToken;
```