# Reading Socket Inputstream Without End Of Transmission Character?

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream, blocking

I'm trying to read the data back from a server program that I didn't write. The server program doesn't send any kind of end of transmission character and it doesn't close the socket once it sends a response. There is a button I can press on the server to close the connection manually and if I leave a little bit of a timeout on the (android)client side so I have time to press it, I do get the data from the server into my client app. Otherwise it just eventually times out and I get no response. Since I can't control the protocol on the server side how can I close the connection and get the response from the server? Thanks for any help.

```
            cSocket.setSoTimeout(timeOut);  

            cOut = new PrintWriter(cSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            cOut.println(msgIn);       

            cIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                cSocket.getInputStream()));   

           int intTest;
           while ((intTest = cSocket.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
           System.out.println(cIn.readLine());
```

Message from the server looks like this: 
char(60)...char(62)char(60)...char(62)char(60)...char(62)char(60)...char(62)

... is random data inside the chars doesn't duplicate.

*Final edit

Got it working like this:

```
int c;
int intCount = 0;
StringBuilder response= new StringBuilder();
while ((c = cIn.read()) != -1) {

    response.append( (char)c ) ; 

       if (c == 62) {
       intCount = intCount + 1;        
       }
       if (intCount >=4) {
           cSocket.close();
           String result = response.toString();
           System.out.println(result);
           break;
       }

}
```

Comment: That's a very odd protocol that doesn't have any way of specifying the end of a transmission.  If you can't know from the content, then I don't imagine you have any way of knowing when to stop reading or take action.

Comment: It seems to send a very strange message within two <> chars at the end of each message. Is there a way I can check for this and somehow close the connection from the client side? It sends something like <!d34f> at the end of each message.

Comment: What *is* the protocol the server is sending? There must be something about it that tells you where the message ends or how long it is. You will have to discover this for yourself, from your requirement specification or the server documentation. We can't tell you. You have to know the protocol anyway (a) to know what to send and (b) how to parse each message received.

Comment: I have the protocol for sending messages, and there is no server doc as the program is no longer under development or being supported. I can see the message it is sending via a console on the server program and I could parse it and split it ok. My issue is my app never receives the message back from the server. Is there a way I can close the socket from the client side or look for the strange tag it sends <!d34f>  at the end somehow from the inputstream to close the loop?

Comment: The protocol for received messages will strongly resemble the protocol for sent messages. Nobody else can help you with this. The fact that the server is no longer under development is not an acceptable reason for there being no documentation or protocol specification. I suggest you escalate this issue to management, as without that specification your task is infeasible. For example one reason you aren't receiving anything could be that you aren't sending in the correct format.

Comment: There has to be a way to get the android app to release the data it has in the inputstream without closing the socket on the server side. Any advice?

Comment: I get a series of integers from socket.read() that indicates to me data is coming into the client app(android) as well as the server console indicating it sent a response. For some reason though socket.readLine() gives me nothing unless I manually close the socket on the server side.

Comment: These questions are pointless. You need to find a protocol description. Guesswork is not going to get you anywhere. NB There is no such method as `Socket.readLine()`, and you haven't posted any code that calls it.

Comment: You're right I'm sorry that was my mistake. If you look at the above code I originally posted I meant cIn.read() and cIn.readLine().

Comment: Like I said there is data coming into my app, and android is blocking apparently. It seems to me it's an android issue that could be solved. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It is blocking because it's trying to read data, because you haven't identifed the end of the message, so you keep reading. The block will continue until the peer sends more data or closes the connection. You said that yourself. This is not an 'Android issue', it is a protocol implementation error on your part, and the only way to solve it is to stop reading when you have the entire message, and the only way to implement that is via the protocol specification. There is no magic bullet.

Comment: I was hoping there was some way to read the contents of inputstream into the app and use it while it's still blocking. I could check for the final weird tag it sends <!d34f> if I could just access the data as it's reading it. Thanks.

Comment: Reading the contents of the input stream and using it while it's still blocking is exactly what the code you posted already does, although you should be printing the byte that was just read, not trying to read an entire new line. The problem remains still that you don't know where one message ends and another starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ((intTest = cSocket.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
    System.out.println(cIn.readLine());
```

This doesn't make any sense. Just because you read a byte doesn't mean you can read another whole line, and you're throwing away the byte you did read. It should be:

```
while ((intTest = cSocket.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
       System.out.println(intTest);
```

And `intTest` is a poor name for an input byte. There's no 'test' about it. I would call it `i`, or `b`.

Comment: I used intTest because it was just a test to see if I was getting anything at all from the inputStream. What I really want is to read the line as a string. The server sends a message that looks like this: <xxx><xxx><xxx><xxx> So today I tried to implement a way to stop the read, I'll edit my original code example with the new code I tried. It's still not working though. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This is what your code example outputs:
60 111 115 49 33 49 53 48 48 62 60 97 108 49 33 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 62 60 97 108 50 33 32 32 32 32  32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 62 60 97 116 49 33 52 62

Comment: It looks like I'm getting the data I need I can see the 60 and 62 chars with the data in between how do I turn this into a string I can use? Also I'm still having to rely on the timeout to break the read. Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind I finally got it working using this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771303/getting-the-character-returned-by-read-in-bufferedreader and your help EJP and a check for 4 char(62) to end the read.

Comment: Reading a byte and then throwing it away isn't a test, it is just a bug. You don't want to read a line, you want to read a *message.* That's what this whole thread is about.